# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysql, database, prepare

I have this error when I am trying to insert data into a database:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   /home/cabox/workspace/views/logged_in.php on line 10

Here is my code:-

```
<?php
include "db_connect.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `posts`(`title`, `content`) VALUES (:title,:content)";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);

    $query->execute(array(
        ':title' => $title,
        ':content' => $content,
    ));
}
?>
```

And here is my database connection:

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$host = "localhost";

$db = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
?>
```

Comment: `mysql*` family don't have prepare option use `mysqli` or `pdo`

Answer (score -1):

try use `global $db;` after include  if you already create the database connection on file db_connect.php 
for php version > 5 .use PDO or mysqli